# (Homework) Converting an NFA to a DFA with an epsilon transition, but no transition for some a in the alphabet

Tags: lambda, state-machine, automata

If my alphabet is {a,b} and my nfa has the following transitions:

```
State    |      a        b        epsilon        
--------------------------------------------
q0              q1      null        q1
q1              q2       q1         none
q2              q2       q1         none
```

Is this table wrong? should delta(q0, b) = q1 because q0 can move on epsilon to state q1?

Comment: I think you are talking about epsilon-transitions right? ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure how to write that into my question as a symbol, I'll edit it to make it more obvious

Comment: if `delta(q0, b) = q1` is wrong depends on transitions in state q1!

Comment: If from q1 (or any state you reach from q1 via epsilon-transition) you reach q1 **when b is read**, **then** `delta(q0, b) = q1` holds for your DFS ;)

Comment: Ah so basically because delta(q0, epsilon) = q1,  then that means delta(q0, b) = delta(q0, epsilon) is that correct?

Comment: what should "1" mean as second argument to `delta`???

Comment: I mistakenly mis-typed that comment, edited just now

Comment: okay, but no, that is wrong ;)

Comment: I see no reason why the transition table you posted should be wrong... as said, **if** it is wrong as you suggested, it would require `delta(q1, b) = q1` ... which I do not know since you did not paste the transition-table of **all** states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As olydis stated in the comments section:

"If from q1 (or any state you reach from q1 via epsilon-transition) you reach q1 when b is read, then delta(q0, b) = q1"